# How to access an Existing JFrame Form?

Tags: java, netbeans, jframe

I'm having a little problem accessing an existing JFrame form (I'm doing this in NetBeans by the way):

```
public class FrameA extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    FrameB b;          //creates a new JFrame called b
    FrameA a = this;    //this JFrame is assigned to a variable a
    String x;
    public FrameA() {
        initComponents();
    }
    private void btnClickMe (java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        x = jTextField1.getText();
        b = new FrameB();       //creates a new instance of FrameB
        b.setVisible (true);    //opens the new JFrame
        a.setVisible(false);    //hides or closes the current JFrame
    }
    public String getMe () {
        return x;                //attempts to get the value of x
    }
}

public class FrameB extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    FrameA a = this.FrameA();       //calls the existing JFrame FrameA
    String clickie = a.getMe(); //attempts to get the x variable from FrameA
           //assigns it to a variable then display on the textarea
    jTextArea1.setText(clickie);
    public FrameB() {
        initComponents();
    }
}
```

I am not so sure what I am doing wrong and am a little confused on how to really access the existing JFrame (FrameA here in this case) from the current JFrame (which is FrameB)

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: There is no existing FrameA. You need to create one using `new`, though perhaps you should first explain what you are trying to achieve. Using more than one JFrame should only be done under specific circumstances. So maybe you're in the wrong direction.

Comment: 'Cause I'm supposed to get the value of x from FrameA since I will be using this value in FrameB. If I try using new, then the x value from FrameA does not exist anymore...

Comment: I'm not sure what you think you have, but in your code as it is, inside `FrameB`, there is no `FrameA` object. The two classes `FrameA` and `FrameB` are two separate, unrelated classes that extend `JFrame`. And the only relation between them is that there is a `FrameA` reference variable  `a` inside `FrameB` which you are initializing with something that doesn't exist. Please edit your question and explain what exactly you are trying to achieve: what windows, what kind of relation between them - the intention, not what you think the code is doing.